# Unsharp edges of lines and models

Tags: wpf, 3d, antialiasing

I have read about it on this link : [How to using anti aliasing in wpf 3d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5219835/how-to-using-anti-aliasing-in-wpf-3d) but unfortunately, there was no answer.

I cannot seem to set the RenderingOptions of my viewport (using the helixtool/helixviewport).

Does anyone know how to increase the sharpness of rendered models?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all if you are running windows XP then multi sampling is off by default, there are reg changes to turn it back on but beyond the scope of this question.

WPF should use multi sampling by default, one thing you should make sure of is that your graphics card meets the min requirements for hardware acceleration with WPF [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742196.aspx) and also that it's not disabled in the graphics card driver control panel.

using the model from the link in your question I got this, which is ugly!
[image]

the setting on my nvidia graphics card that was making this happen is displayed below.[image]

once I changed the OFF to application controlled, WPF started to use it's multi sampling

[image]

Comment: I am using windows xp. But thanks for the detailed information.

Comment: Take a look at the 'Maximum Multisample Value' section on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970912.aspx it's quite easy to turn it back on. Apparently they turned it off on Windows XP because it causes too many crashes on older drivers.